# Node / Forever being killed on CentOS?

Tags: node.js, centos, forever

When using NodeJS/Forever on CentOS, my script randomly gets caught in cycles of receiving "SIGKILL" and restarting. It does this every 1-2 seconds, and the Forever log shows things like:

```
2013-11-18T20:42:18.200Z - error: Forever detected script was killed by signal: SIGKILL
```

This is a server environment, and no one is killing the script manually. Am I missing something in my CentOS config that may be killing processes after a certain amount of uptime or something?

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
-Nate

Comment: We did discover that memory use was spiking, so this might be the OOM Killer, but our findings are inconclusive and we're still looking into it.

Comment: any idea, mine dies with forever but works regular when run with node

Comment: Possibly Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136291/will-linux-start-killing-my-processes-without-asking-me-if-memory-gets-short

Comment: Hey Nate, did you find a solution for this?

Comment: i would try pm2 instead of forever. Its much more advanced, you wont look back.